# May I know why I am getting "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter" even the closure is non-escaping?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function

```
static func promptToHandleAutoLink(onEdit: () -> ()) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default) { _ in
        onEdit()
    })

    ...
}
```

I am getting the compilation error

> Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'onEdit'

When I look at the defination of `UIAlertAction` constructor, it looks like

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
@MainActor open class UIAlertAction : NSObject, NSCopying {

    
    public convenience init(title: String?, style: UIAlertAction.Style, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil)
}
```

As, there is no `@escaping` keyword for `handler`, I thought `handler` suppose to be a non-escaping closure.

If that is so, why I am getting such compiler error?

I know I can solve this issue by simply adding `@escaping` keyword on `onEdit`.

```
static func promptToHandleAutoLink(onEdit: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default) { _ in
        onEdit()
    })

    ...
}
```

But still, I would like to understand, the reason I am getting such compiler error, because `UIAlertAction`'s `handler` seems like a non-escaping closure.

Thanks.

Comment: If optional, you can skip the `@escaping`. In this case it's escaping, because the method will reach its ends, before the closure gets called by a user action.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass a closure to your function and this closure will be called at some later point in the future, i.e. after the function returns, you have to mark it as an `@escaping` closure. In your particular case, the closure is stored in memory because you called it in the completion parameter of the `alert.addAction` method, i.e. it will be called whenever the user clicks on the corresponding alert view's button, so it has to "escape" the function scope and live somewhere else in the memory.

Comment: The closure to `UIAlertAction` is escaping because `handler:` is an _optional_ closure, which automatically makes it escaping even though there's no explicit `@escape` here. That's what confused OP and what needs explanation.